# Sendmail + Smart Relay: don't forward mail to local accounts

Tags: sendmail, smarthost

I have a problem with my sendmail config. Need to use a smart host, but local services that send mail to local accounts need to post local.

I use this lines

```
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`localhost.localdomain')dnl
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`acme.com')dnl
```

… and file /etc/mail/local-host-names

Any idea. Need more info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I can find around, the following macro directs sendmail to use the `esmtp` mailer for "local" mail instead of sending it through the smart relay.

```
LOCAL_NET_CONFIG
R$* < @ $* .$m. > $*    $#esmtp $@ $2.$m $: $1 < @ $2.$m. > $3
```

On my systems, these are the last two lines in the default `sendmail.mc`, as shipped.

Depending on exactly how local your "local accounts" are, you may want to use `$#local` in place of `$#esmtp`, after suitable testing.

Comment: Good. Works great!
as observation, use a tab in the rule:
`R$* < @ $* .$m. > $*[TAB]$#smtp $@ $2.$m $: $1 < @ $2.$m. > $3`